# Git: removing remote branch after removing it locally

Tags: git, github

I had 2 branches in my local and remote repository: `master` and `test`. After merging `test` into `master` I pushed `master` to `origin`. Now, when I no longer needed branch `test`, I removed it from my local repository. I would like to remove the unwanted branch from `origin`. Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to do it.

I heave read about `git fetch -p`, but this is the opposite of what I want to do. I have also tried `git push origin --delete origin/test`, but all I have got was this error message:

```
error: unable to delete 'origin/test': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:myaccount/myrepository.git'
```

Concluding. Is there some way to remove remotely branch that do not exist locally? Or did I make a mistake and after removing local branch I do not have control over its remote instance. I know that I can manually remove branch from github on their website, but is there a way to do this from my local machine using `git`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple: `origin/test` is *your* Git's name for this.  But on *their* Git, *their* name for this is just `test`.  You have to have your Git ask their Git to delete their name `test`.

The `origin/*` names that your Git has are your Git's way of *copying* their Git's *branch* names.  So `origin/*` aren't *branch* names at all.  They are, instead, *remote-tracking names*.<sup>1</sup>  Your Git sees their branch name `X` and says: *Aha, I'll copy that—but to make sure I don't mess up my own `X`, I'll call it `origin/X` instead.*

You may wish to run `git fetch --prune`, or set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration.  Then, after you run `git fetch origin`, if your Git sees that their Git no longer has a branch name `X`, your Git will *delete* your `origin/X` if you have one.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find the word *branch* in here just makes things confusing.  They aren't actually *branch* names in your Git.  They're just copied from someone else's branch names.  So let's call them something without the word "branch" in it.

Comment: but this branch exists on _my_ Git and not on _their_ Git. I want _my_ Git to tell _their_ Git to delete _their_ branch.

Comment: Branches, in the sense you're thinking of, don't matter. Branch *names* exist, and *commits* exist. Just delete the name: in this case, `git push origin --delete test`, to ask them to delete their name `test`.